# regex repetitive parts in monetary amounts

Tags: php, regex

In a monetary pattern I look for thousand separator

```
(?:[. ]\d{3})*
```

In this case the thousand separator could either be `.` or  . But how to make sure that the pattern will not match patterns where the thousand separator is mixed?

Only match patterns like

```
.123.123.123
 123 123 123
```

Do not match

```
.123 123 123.123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match the first separator and then use a backreference to match the same separator for the remaining digit groups:

```
^(?:([. ])\d{3}(\1\d{3})*)?$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/u4zPuf/1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to match empty strings:

```
^([. ])\d{3}(?:\1\d{3})*$
```

In parts the pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `([. ])` Capture **group 1**, match either `.` or a space
- `\d{3}` Match 3 digits
- `(?:\1\d{3})*` Optionally repeat a back reference to what is captured in group 1 followed by 3 digits
- `$` End of strings

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UQx4CW/1)